# How to upload file to server with django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I've found [this very simple code](https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example/tree/master/src/for_django_1-9/myproject/myproject/myapp) for my problem but I've tried to repeat it in my project and there was no result.
I think I do everything correctly but result is bad.

I do so:

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='select file pls'
    )
```

views.py

```
class CabinetView(TemplateView, UploadFileForm):
    template_name = 'cabinet.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated() or self.request.user.is_anonymous():
        raise ValueError('You are not log in. Please do it.')
    context = super(CabinetView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.first_name:
        context['current_user'] = self.request.user.first_name
    else:
        context['current_user'] = self.request.user

    return context

def post(self, request):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_file = self.request.FILES['docfile']
            print my_file.name
        else:
            print 'invalid'
    return render(self.request, 'cabinet.html', {'form': form})
```

html template:

```
<body>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
</form>
</body>
```

I'm waiting for uploading file, but when I'm trying to do it (I have button "browse..." and I try to push it after choosing file) terminal says:

```
POST /cabinet/ HTTP/1.1 200 5740

form: <tr><th><label for="id_docfile">select file pls:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_docfile" name="docfile" type="file" /></td></tr>

invalid
```

So, form is invalid. I can't understand why.

Sorry for very simple question.
If there are any problems im my questions I'm sorry. It's my first question at stackoverflow.

My settings are:
Python 2.7
Django 1.9.7
Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form, so the file you are uploading will be saved.

Comment: Have you setup MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: > add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form
oh, miracle! Thank you very mush. I've thought that this is only for uploading several files. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
my_file = self.request.FILES['file']
```

with

```
my_file = self.request.FILES['docfile']
```

in your views.py

Comment: Thanks. But I have the same yet. Changed it in question.